# How resilient should my web app be?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception

Lately, I've found myself in quite a few arguments with my boss about the handling of exceptions within our web app (a c# asp.net MVC application).

Basically the conversations go something like this:

Boss: "There is something wrong with our program, client x's database went down today and everyone is seeing the error page."

Me: "Mostly every page in the application uses the database for something (except the error page), there is no reasonable alternative other than to show the error page."

Boss: "Our application should be more resilient -- the part of the application that don't require database access should still function."

Often, the cases are as extreme as this, but sometimes we run into a case where we are integrating with another service where we can still safely show other portions of the page, or complete the operation, albeit with some annoying code as later portions of code need to later use the results of the operation which may have failed. If there are many points of possible failure this can turn into some extremely unmanageable code.

In general, for a "normal" web application (not mission-critical, etc...) how much time do "good" developers spend trying to make their code resilient enough to handle these kind of situations. My boss seems to think that the code should be able handle almost any situation (can't you just catch an exception?). I don't see how this can be economical when there are many possible points of failure.

Comment: In this economy, do what you boss tell you.

Comment: The database example is perhaps a little extreme and oversimplified. Basically we have some pages that interact with multiple 3rd party services - geocoding/facebook/etc... There may be several calls to a given service made in the execution of a page. Results from one service may be later passed to another or used in the rendering of the page. Assuming that any one of these may be down and trying to produce sensible output in every case seems to become very difficult in the presence of many of these services.

Comment: How useful is your error page. If for a moment, you were an end-user, what would you like to see?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd leave it to the boss to decide. Tell him an estimate in hours how long it would take to make the app "resilient" and he'll decide if it's worth the investment.

Comment: This is, in fact, the approach I usually take. It is usually quite effective though I sometimes perceive the sentiment that my estimates are overblown and it should be a matter of "just catching an exception" which it rarely is.

Answer (score 7):

Most apps that I've worked on that are heavily data driven have redirected to a custom error page when the main database (ie the one that powers 99% of the pages) is down.  (you do want to be showing them a custom screen though, not just letting them get the server error page)

For external services like hitting an SMTP server or a database that isn't used by much of the rest of the app we'll usually have code around it that just displays on-page feedback if the service/database is down/inaccessible.

Its really up the client/stakeholder though, just determine what they want to have happen when the database is down and do it for them.  It'll take time but it shouldn't lead to an unmaintainable app or any other coding horror.

Answer (score 3):

I guess I'd be a little worried that you're losing databases with a frequency that causes this question to arise.  Even in non-mission critical apps, if you're losing a DB more than once a week, I'd be seeing what I could do about improving that before I worried about crafting ways out of the issue on the user end of the application.

That being said, my company's best practices include coding so that something such as a DB error will failover gracefully on the user end to a "cannot connect" message in the output rather than a full blown 404 type error.  I've found that it really doesn't add more than a few minutes to the coding process, and the value of not angering the user is well worth the "cost"

Comment: Perhaps the database example wasn't a good one as it is a little extreme. It is usually a matter of integrating with third party web services and the like.

Answer (score 3):

Your boss should have discussed with the customer, before creating the application. Terms like "non-critical" should be defined as a number (percentage of uptime). Some applications require different parts of the application to have different numbers of uptime (what your boss suggests) and applications are up/down as a whole (how it works now). The "resilient" application will probably be written in a different way (distributed reads/async writes, etc.) than the "normal" application, so it will (probably) be hard to convert the "normal" application.

A good boss discusses a good SLA with the customer of the application, and tells it to the developers before the development start. On the other side, a good developer should complain by his boss, about incomplete requirements before starting development. When nothing is mentioned about availability in the requirements, the requirements are incomplete.

When the availability or scalability requirements of an existing application change significantly, it might be very hard to make the changes in an application profitable. When you have a good boss, those requirements will only change significantly when the application has a lot more success then initially estimated (like 100 times more users). In that case the enormous success will generate enough money to make the it profitable to rewrite huge parts of the application.

Answer (score 2):

It depends... many web pages display and render individual "widgets".  Each widget may draw from a different data source... some may even be completely static.  I agree with your boss from the standpoint that if loading one widget fails for whatever reason, we should still try to load the rest of the page.  One failed widget should not keep the user from interacting with the rest of the site.

As an example from StackOverflow, lets say that the "Related" section to the right of these answers fails to load, or that the footer fails to load for some reason.  I'd say it's preferable to just display some error message in those portions of the page and still load your question and the answers, since these should be unaffected.

Now, there are situations when the code which loads all those "widgets" fails... or some data source used by your framework fails.  In these cases, I think it is reasonable to display a generic error page... If the framework or "widget" loading code fails for whatever reason, this is indeed an exceptional case that probably can't be handled.

In sum, I mostly agree with your boss and say that as many error cases as possible should be considered and handled... and that we should be displaying whatever possible to the user.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a more academic answer given that you've inherited this code.  If you use, or rather if someone had used, the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling ExceptionPolicy pattern then it is really easy to switch from showing an error page (by throwing exception) to eating exceptions and displaying empty grids, lists, etc.

You may already be aware of this little pattern, but here it is anyway:

```
        try
        {
            //get data
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Data Access Exception"))
                throw ex;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're just showing an generic error page when an empty set of data with and a "user-friendly" error message would do.

So, for instance, if you're displaying a list of users/messages/date but the service where you collect it, is down, you could probably show an empty set.

So instead of showing:

```
500 Server Error




.
```

You could show something like:

```
 User   |    Message     | Date 
 ------------------------------
    No data available* 




* Xyz service is be down.
```

Your app still won't work, because the data is not available, but instead of throwing that to the end-user face, you could put a placeholder with no data.

This varies a lot depending on what you use, but in general terms it could be as simple as:

```
 List<Data> data = EmptyList<Data>();

 try 
 {
     data = service.GetData();
 } catch( ServiceUnavailableException error ) 
 {
     errorPage.SetMessage( service.GetName() + " service is down ");
     // log the error message
    logger.doLog( error );
 }
```

That is, initialize your list or whatever structure to something empty, then fill with with the service, and if it fails ( then the list will remain empty )  add an error message ( user friendly please )  and log the exception.

Answer (score -1):

I think that once we start practicing something, building resilient applications for e.g., we spend little time in categorising as normal or mission critical and start building resilient, ha, scalable etc application to deal with failures.

More Effort is definitely needed to ensure resilient apps, however once that knowledge is gained and implemented, 
Next time ,it becomes a lot easier.
Generic libraries like spring or Netflix's circuit breaker are already available which on integration, can deal with failures gracefully in some aspects.
Retrying an idempotent operation is easy to implement as well.

To make an application usable, it has to be available and reliable.
Almost all applications ( other than standalone desktop utilities) are 2 or more tiered applications which means network call will be there and all n/w related problems. 
So, once you start practicing, you will start implementing resiliency patterns in all applications.

Comment: The question itself is (now) off-topic (notice it was published over 7 years ago). Even the accepted answer is merely an opinion. Please don't add to this with more opinion (yours being of the n-tier variety, and not considering modern microservice architecture). Also, I removed the link to your blog - this isn't the place for it.